# SQL Server: check if string contains numbers (single or double digits)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure and I want to pass a string parameter which contains numbers representing the steps that need to be executed.

For example:

```
dc.SProcCP("1,2,14,24") //steps 1, 2, 14 and 24 need to be executed
```

In my stored procedure, I have a set of `if`s . Each one checks if the input argument contains a step.  Like in the first `if` :

```
if (CHARINDEX("1",@inputsteps)>0 ....
```

But this will be true if steps contain "1" or if steps contain "14".

How I can solve this?

Comment: split your string into varchar parts and cast every part to integer

Comment: @sepupic can write the code for that?

Comment: just search for SplitStr functions in internet

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply check like below

```
if (CHARINDEX('1,',CONCAT(@inputsteps,','))>0 ....
```

Comment: @aggicd I'd advise that the first line in proc should be `SET @inputsteps= CONCAT(@inputsteps+',')`; does not make sense to do same operation agian and again, increasing SQL processing

Comment: Try this with @inputsteps varchar(100) ='11,24'